# Function for n-th term in sequence that doubles in length on reaching modulus

Tags: sequences-and-series, modular-arithmetic

Does a $f(x)$ exist that could return the *n*-th term for the sequence below?

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, …
```

For example, I am able to solve it in an iterative manner for $f(15) = 5$ using the following pseudo-code:

```
let i = 0;
let j = 0;
let k = 1;
let n = 14;
    
while n > 0 {
    j = (j + 1) % k;
        
    if (j + 1) % k == 0 {
        i = (i + 1) % 5;
            
        if (i + 1) % 5 == 0 {
            k = k * 2;
        }
    }
        
    n = n - 1;
}

// i + 1 = 5
```

However, this is highly inefficient and I wondered if there is a non-iterative way to find the *n*-th term of this sequence?

It feels as if there are many ways to solve this, e.g. perhaps even using trigonometry, but I'm somewhat out of my depth here. Pointers would very much be appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$a=\Big\lceil\log_2\left(\Big\lceil\frac{x}{5}\Big\rceil+1\right)\Big\rceil$$

$$f(x)=\Bigg\lceil\frac{x-5*2^{a-1}+5}{2^{a-1}}\Bigg\rceil$$

$2^{a-1}$ is the number of repetitions of each number in the block you are in.  Starting with $x=1 \rightarrow a=1 \rightarrow 2^{a-1}=1$

Comment: You might comment that $a$ is the number of repetitions of each number in the block you are in and that you are starting with $x=0$ for the first term.